# How do I set a boolean flag on a different view Controller from another?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have this code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    var segue = UIStoryboardSegue()
    let viewController = ViewController()
    viewController.check == true
    let photo1 = photos[indexPath.row]
    viewController.photo = photo1
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    return true
}
```

I only want certain code to execute if an item is selected. So my plan is to create a flag for checking.
The problem here is the flag `viewController.check == true` never gets set to true when I arrive on the next view controller. I have tested it with `println()` and stuff, it's not setting at all. What am I doing wrong? How else should I do it?

Comment: You should set the "flag" in the `prepareForSegue`
 method

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but why are you using the equality operator `==` when trying to assign `true` to `viewController.check`?
In that case you would have to use the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: @MarcusRossel thanks. always little mistakes like that take my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `performSegueWithIdentifier` method instantiates a new instance of view controller. In the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method set your flag to `segue.destinationViewController`:

```
segue.destinationViewController.check = true
```